# To compute a distribution

Tags: distribution-theory

Given $F_n\in C^\infty_0$ given by $F_n(\varphi)=\left(\varphi\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-\varphi\left(-\frac{1}{n}\right)  \right)$.

Then what is the distribution given by $\lim_n F_n?$.

The problem lies in how the limit will behave, because it doesn't looks there is a limit at all.

Comment: On any smooth test function, $\lim_{n} F_{n}$ makes sense and equals $\varphi(0)-\varphi(0)=0,$ so I would venture that if the limit exists, it should be the $0$ distribution. You would need to prove that $F_{n}\rightarrow F(=0)$ however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @RideTheWavelet says, for every test function $\varphi$, the limit of $F_n(\varphi)$ is $0$, because of continuity at $0$ of such $\varphi$. Thus, by the definition of the weak dual topology on distributions, $\lim_n F_n=0$ (where limit is taken in that topology).

Comment: Therefore, the distribution is zero as well, right?

Comment: The fact that $F_n$ converges to the zero distribution is given by the definition of the weak dual topology? Because $\lim_n F_n$ is zero, but I'm confused on how to show $F_n$ converges to the zero distribution.

Comment: The topology on distributions is exactly that $u_n\to u$ if and only if for every test function $\varphi$ $u_n(\varphi)\to u(\varphi)$ as a numerical limit. Maybe it's "too easy"!?! :)